# How to fix "the break code" problem in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, pycharm, break

I try to learn Python. The code can be written super easily but doesn't work. And when I write "break", it doesn't show up in the suggestions of PyCharm. I watch videos on Youtube and I did the same things that I watched. The same code works on the video, but in mine computer it doesn't work. What is the problem and how can I fix this?

```
s_Number=9
guess_count=0
guess_limit=3
while guess_count<guess_limit:
    number = input("Guess a number: ")
     guess_count+=1
  if number==s_Number:

      print("Well done!")
   break
```

Comment: `input` returns a `str`. Instead, try `if int(number) == s_Number`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf  SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

Comment: Clearly an indentation error.

Comment: The `break` needs to be indented appropriately, i.e. same number of spaces/tabs your `print` statement is

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop` is caused due to your wrong indentation.

```
s_Number=9
guess_count=0
guess_limit=3
while guess_count<guess_limit:
     number = input("Guess a number: ")
     guess_count+=1
     if number==s_Number:
         print("Well done!")
     break
```

You can also place your `break` statement inside your `if` depending upon your intent.

Comment: The `break` needs to be inside the `if` statement, otherwise the while loop is useless.

Comment: Python has different syntax rules than others. I still can not get used to it. Thanks again